# Button value is not posted to Controller while Form Submit?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, forms

In my View, there are two `<input type="image">` tags, and they are inside a Form.
In my Controller, the value of these two `<input type="image">` always appears as 'null'. Earlier, with `<input type="submit">`, the values were posted to the controller.Now they're not.Can anyone tell me how to access those values in the Controller?

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Load", "Consent"))
{

//some code

<div id="button1" style="right:150px; width:90px; bottom :15px;position:absolute"><input type="image" src="../../img/ButtonBack.png" name="button" value="Previous" id="back" /></div>
<div id="button2" style="right:20px; width:90px; bottom :15px; position:absolute"><input type="image" src="../../img/ButtonNext.png" name="button" value="Acknowledge" id="ack" /></div>
</div>
}
```

The Form is getting posted to the controller, but the value of `string button` is 'null'

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Load(bool? chk_acknowledge, string button)
        {
           // some code
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is not required to post the value of the "value" attribute, so don't rely on it. Value is meant for radio and checkbox input fields: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-INPUT

However, browsers will post two other form fields: *name*.x and *name*.y. You could instead name your two image buttons "nextButton" and "prevButton". In your action, check if Request.Form contains "nextButton.x". If it exists, nextButton has been pressed. Likewise, if "prevButton.x" exists, prevButton has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Only the value of the **clicked** *image button* would be posted (only the clicked submit button). While having the 2 image buttons inside a form, if there is another submit button and you click on that, the image buttons would not get posted.

Eg : You click on first image button inside div#button1 - in the post array, there would be `[button] => Previous` the other image button will not get posted.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1):

> When a pointing device is used to click on the image, the form is
>   submitted and the click coordinates passed to the server. The x value
>   is measured in pixels from the left of the image, and the y value in
>   pixels from the top of the image. The submitted data includes
>   name.x=x-value and name.y=y-value where "name" is the value of the
>   name attribute, and x-value and y-value are the x and y coordinate
>   values, respectively.

So:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Load", "Consent"))
{
    ... some code

    <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/img/ButtonBack.png")" name="Previous" />
    <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/img/ButtonNext.png")" name="Acknowledge" />
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Load(bool? chk_acknowledge)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["previous.x"]))
    {
        // the Previous image button was clicked
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["acknowledge.x"]))
    {
        // the Acknowledge image button was clicked
    }

    ...
}
```